# How to pass selected records i.e, list of records which isn't related to any sObject and Custom Object from LWC to Flow

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, lightning-flow-builder

I'm having a list of records which isn't related to any custom or standard object I need to pass it to Flow. how to pass the list of records from LWC to flow using  in js-meta.xml and also help me what kind of flow resource I need to create so that I can bind the selected records to flow resource variable.

this what I have created in js-meta.xml

```
        <propertyType extends="SObject" name="T" label="Select SObject"/>
        <property name="records2" type="{T[]}" label="Records U" />
```

and in flow I've created 'records2' resource as a collection variable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Input/Output variable in LWC component in Flow](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/348674/how-to-get-input-output-variable-in-lwc-component-in-flow)